# ReactiveProperty initial value

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, reactive-property

I'm trying to set an initial value to the `public ReactiveProperty<string> ConnectionStatus`.

```
public ViewModelConstructor()
{
    ConnectionStatus = Observable
                    .Interval(RefreshInterval)
                    .Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => networkDiscovererService.CanDiscoverAsync("192.168.1.1", RequestTimeout)))
                    .Concat()
                    .Select(isConnected => isConnected ? $"connected" : $"not connected")
                    .ToReactiveProperty();
}
```

Even if I'm trying to instantiate it like this

```
public ReactiveProperty<string> ConnectionStatus { get; } =
            new ReactiveProperty<string>("Checking connectivity...");
```

It's still empty until the observable returns something.

Any ideas? I'm using this [library](https://github.com/runceel/ReactiveProperty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get initial value on subscribe (like behaviorSubject, or Replay(1)) using ReactiveProperty ctor:

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldReturnAValuOnSubscribe()
    {
        var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var testableObserver = testScheduler.CreateObserver<int>();

        var reactiveProperty = new ReactiveProperty<int>(30);
        reactiveProperty.Subscribe(testableObserver);

        Assert.AreEqual(30, testableObserver.Messages.Single().Value.Value);
    }
```

To get initial value on subscribe (like behaviorSubject, or Replay(1)) using .ToReactiveProperty():

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldReturnAValuOnToReactiveProperty()
    {
        var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var testableObserver = testScheduler.CreateObserver<int>();

        var reactiveProperty = Observable.Never<int>().ToReactiveProperty(40);
        reactiveProperty.Subscribe(testableObserver);

        Assert.AreEqual(40, testableObserver.Messages.Single().Value.Value);
    }
```

NOT to get initial value on subscribe - change ReactivePropertyMode:

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldNotReturnAnInitialValue_WhenModeIsNone_AndOnSubscribe()
    {
        var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var testableObserver = testScheduler.CreateObserver<int>();

        var reactiveProperty = new ReactiveProperty<int>(30, ReactivePropertyMode.None);
        reactiveProperty.Subscribe(testableObserver);

        Assert.IsEmpty(testableObserver.Messages);
    }
```

Basically, what you're looking for is **initial value** and **ReactivePropertyMode.RaiseLatestValueOnSubscribe** flag.

In the first case you forgot to provider ToReactiveProperty() with initial value (e.g. ToReactiveProperty(30))

It should've worked for you in the second case - the mode is set to **ReactivePropertyMode.RaiseLatestValueOnSubscribe** by default (check ShouldReturnAValuOnSubscribe). Try to set the mode explicitly (like in **ShouldNotReturnAnInitialValue_WhenModeIsNone_AndOnSubscribe**).

I used ReactiveProperty 3.6.0.

btw, It's not a very good idea to test a connection based on timer :)

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Do you have any recommendations regarding timer-based connection tester? It's for real-time streaming data from a device on the network, so I need to notify the user if the device is unavailable.

Comment: Hi @GabrielRobert. I don't know the internals of your networkDiscovererService  class but usually this kind of classes have something like Connected/Disconnected events to report status. Timer-based connectivity should be your last resort in this case :)

Comment: It’s just a ping service targeting an IP. I trigger a ping every few seconds to make sure it’s always reachable. To be reachabable, the user need to be on the same device’s wifi.